# Pandas: Subset a data frame by column names NOT wanted

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subset

To subset a dataframe by column names I usually do:

```
df[['A', 'B']]
```

where `list(df.columns.values) = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

Say I instead wanted to get all the columns except `'B'`. How would I do this? This apparently does not work:

```
df[!['B']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`drop` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df.drop('B', axis=1)
```

`drop` can also accept a list of columns, if you wish to drop more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ix to achieve this by requesting the rows you want (in this case all) and the columns you want (or dont). For example:

```
df.ix [:, df.columns != 'B']
```

Would get you all rows for all columns except 'B'

Comment: how do I proceed when I don't want B and C?